# Possible reasons why my Alexa turns on the wrong light

Tags: smart-home, networking, alexa, amazon-echo

We have multiple IoT devices at home. For this explanation, we're concerned about the bedroom lights and kitchen lights. I have two Alexa devices, the main one is in the kitchen (Echo Show) and the other one is in the bedroom (Echo Dot). Whenever I tell Alexa in the bedroom to turn on the bedroom light, she would say, "Ok".

The problem here is that she would turn on the kitchen light, not the bedroom light.

I checked the app on my phone and it seems that they are correctly named. I tried disconnecting and reconnecting the bedroom lights but it's still the same - whenever I would ask Alexa to turn on the bedroom lights, she would turn on the kitchen lights. When I ask her to turn on the kitchen lights though, she does turn on the kitchen lights.

I'm trying to understand what's going on so I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you move your bedroom dot from the kitchen by any chance? Sometimes moving them around from one room to another when you acquire an additional device can inadvertently cause chaos which requires reconfiguring some settings and routines.

Do you have any routines setup with custom voice commands? Maybe your voice command of "turn on the bedroom light" is triggering a routine that's actually turning on the kitchen lights.

If you have any rooms or "groups" set up in the Alexa app I would check there also. Go into the "Devices" tab in the Alexa app and scroll down to the bottom. If there is a "bedroom" group listed click on it then "edit" in the upper right. This gives you the ability to associate an Alexa device with that group. So, for example, if you're in the bedroom talking to the bedroom dot you can just say "turn on the lights" and she'll turn on the bedroom lights. However, if you're in the kitchen talking to the kitchen show and say "turn on the lights" she'll turn on the kitchen lights.

If you don't have any groups setup I would start by creating a group for the bedroom and one for the kitchen. Add the dot to the bedroom group and the show to the kitchen group. Make sure you also add your lights to their respective group. This will hopefully get it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons this could happen.

- It misheard you, but that appears to be not likely.  You can view the voice history on your app and see what happened.  You can also flag the ones that were misheard
- If you swap the smart switch between the two rooms and Alexa has not been resynced. You can do this in

  - Devices
  - Press +
  - Add New Device
  - Select your Device-family

  and it will resync.